# jQuery Autocomplete > Select > Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this code implemented and I like how straight forward it is because I plan to add ALOT to the Source -- however for the life of me I cannot figure out how to add the selected one as a Link.

EG > Begin Typing > Autofill works > Select > Go to that URL

**Current Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["NYC", "LA", "Philly", "Chitown", "DC", "SF", "Peru"]
});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<input id="autocomplete" />

</body>
</html>
```

I found a few discussions about this on here, but none of the code suggestions had worked. How do I add a URL associated with the values above; I'd love if I could keep the same syntax and near the values just add; EG: "peru" www.peru.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could add a `url` property to each object in the source array and then set `window.location` to that URL when the user selects an item:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [
             { value: "NYC", url: 'http://www.nyc.com' }, 
             { value: "LA", url: 'http://www.la.com' },
             { value: "Philly", url: 'http://www.philly.com' },
             { value: "Chitown", url: 'http://www.chitown.com' },
             { value: "DC", url: 'http://www.washingtondc.com' },
             { value: "SF", url: 'http://www.sanfran.com' },
             { value: "Peru", url: 'http://www.peru.com' }
        ],
        select: function (event, ui) {
            window.location = ui.item.url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: AH. Sorry, they will not be exact Name > .com; Some will be "NYC" > www.samplenotnyc.com -- I was just hoping to have the URL near the value within the code for updating.

Comment: So can you change the `source` array? I'm not sure what you mean by "Near the value"

Comment: Actually I think I see what you mean. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: YES! This looks great -- let me give it a whirl, thanks dude!

Comment: Would there be any limit / issue adding a few hundred values with this code?

Comment: Mmm, I don't think a few hundred would matter, but when you get into the thousands you would definitely want to consider using a server-side source.

Comment: super , can i also add source.php in place of the json values ?